# Make PhpStorm navigate to stylus class

Tags: phpstorm, stylus

I use stylus in PhpStorm. Therefore I’ve got both files .css and .styl.
When I press <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> on any class inside html PhpStorm sends me to the class inside `.css` file instead of `.styl`.

How to make PhpStorm navigate straight to style class inside the `.styl` file?

Comment: AFAIK -- nope. Not exact matches but related (same story) 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6737 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6962 3) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8190 4) maybe even https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23270

Comment: If you think that Stylus deserves own ticket -- feel free to create one (and devs will decide if such separate ticket is needed; I say -- no).